# access 2010 expression builder

Tags: ms-access, default-value

I want a text box to contain data which is a calculation based on 2 other control field values - only if it's value is null (ie the current value of the column in the database is null).

So I entered =([control1]*[Control2])/1000 in the expression builder for the default value property - however the result always shows the textbox to be empty (even tho control2 and control2 contain values).

How can I achieve this? Can such an operation only be done in code-behind ie VB??

thanks,

KS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about a control bound to a field in the form's record source.  And when the underlying field is Null, you want the control loaded with your calculated value.

If that interpretation is correct, you can do it from the form's On Current event.

```
If IsNull(Me.txtYourTextBox) Then
    Me.txtYourTextBox = (Nz(Me.control1) * Nz(Me.Control2)) / 1000
End If
```

That will load the computed value into the text box, allow the user to change its value if desired, and store the value to the bound field when the record is saved.

If the bound field is not Null, its value will be displayed in the text box without alteration by the On Current code.

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am after - was just hoping that it could be done as an expression - but no big deal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this using VBA, add a Form_Load Event. (Open the form in Design View and in Form properties click the Event tab and choose Event Procedure for "On Load" and click ...)
This example uses [TextField] to refer to the table data.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  TextControl.SetFocus
  If IsNull([TextField]) Then
    TextControl.Text = ([Control1] * [Control2]) / 1000
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like VBA is the only way.

Comment: It does. I tried similar code using IIf(...) to set the DefaultValue, but it did not set the TextBox for reasons I cannot explain at the moment.

Comment: I do not believe the load event is suitable unless the form is to display only one record. I would go for the current event and probably the after update events of the two relevant controls. It is necessary to know the flow of the form in order to choose the most appropriate event(s).